# Short-cut to jump from find panel to editor view?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

In Sublime Text 3 (on Ubuntu), when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> the find panel is shown and its text input is focused. Pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> hides the find panel and focus is returned to the editor view. Is there a short-cut or a command that can be used to refocus the editor view without closing the find panel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the easiest way to establish this is to use the focus group command `ctrl+1`. With this you focus the editor in the first editor group. Using `ctrl+f` you can easily jump back to the search input.

If you have split window you can also use `ctrl+2`, `ctrl+3`, ... to focus the editors of the other groups.

Comment: It's not a perfect solution but it's certainly an improvement.